how to set my own message in event.returnValue in beforeunload function
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
  event.returnValue = 'Are you sure you want to leave this page?' 
  updateapi();    
 })

I want to show above message only instead default message coming from chrome .I tried alert but its giving blocked error, any alternative solution for this?

read docs - I think you're trying to use it in a legacy manner anyway - i.e. I don't think any modern browsers actually support using your own message
